# Return dataframe from dask.dataframe.apply() and not series with nested dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm applying a function to a `dask.dataframe`. The function returns a`pd.Dataframe`. Now I  I would like the result from `dask.dataframe.apply()` to be the concatenated dataframes returned by the function. However, apply returns a pd.Series with the dataframes nested inside that series. It's straightforward to unpack the series into one dataframe, but I think there should be a better solution.

Toy sample:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd


vals = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=4)


def func(params):
    return pd.DataFrame({"A": params[0] * vals, "B": params[1] * vals})


df = pd.DataFrame({"X": vals, "Y": vals, "Z": vals})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

result = ddf.apply(lambda x: func((x.Y, x.Z)), axis=1).compute()

print(type(result))  # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(pd.concat(result.values)))  # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

Comment: If your function returns a dataframe with the same index as the original, you probably should be using [`df.map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html) not df.apply. Your toy example could be done with dask.dataframe operations directly rather than applying a function but I'm guessing that's not true of your (non-toy) real application?

Comment: Yes, the real application cannot be computed with dask operations. However, how would you use `df.map_partitions` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is a different take on the problem, but since it appears that you are doing some sort of grid search/evaluation, this approach might work:

```py
from dask import delayed
from dask.dataframe import concat, from_delayed
from numpy.random import randint

vals = randint(0, 20, size=4)


@delayed
def func(*params):
    return pd.DataFrame({"A": params[0] * vals, "B": params[1] * vals})


ddf = concat([from_delayed(func(x, y, z)) for x, y, z in zip(vals, vals, vals)])

print(ddf.head())
#      A    B
# 0  144  144
# 1   12   12
# 2  108  108
# 3   12   12
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is how I resolved it.

Comment: Another solution was to load the iterator into `dask.bag` and map the function over the bag.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good approach.